# how to implement effect like the windows 7 calendar does

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When you open the date-time dialog in windows 7, and you click on the year-month label, the dialog will switch to month selecting page with a nice animate effect. how can we do the same thing with jquery and jquery ui?
[image]

Comment: @Leon I tried fadeIn(), show('scale')....no luck, I mean all those effects provided by jquery and jquery ui don't look like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

[try this have some variant like it](http://aryweb.nl/projects/mootools-datepicker/Test/)
link: http://aryweb.nl/projects/mootools-datepicker/Test/